# Java: Finding how many words appear in BOTH data sources?

Tags: java, string, compare

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easy way to count the number of words that appear in small paragraph (#1) and small paragraph (#2).

Generally, Im determining how much overlap there is in these paragraphs on a word by word basis.  So if (#1) contains the word "happy" and (#2) contains the word "happy" that would be like a +1 value.

I know that I could use a `String.contains()` for each word in (#1) applied to (#2).  But I was wondering if there is something more efficient that I could use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create two sets s1 and s2, containing all words from first and second paragraph respectively, and intersect them: `s1.retainAll(s2)`. Sounds easy enough.

**update**
Works for me

```
    Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("abc xyz 123".split("\\s")));
    Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("xyz 000 111".split("\\s")));
    s1.retainAll(s2);
    System.out.println(s1.size());
```

Don't forget to remove empty word from both sets.

Comment: I was just typing out a complicated algorithm but this is much cleaner lol.  +1 for knowing the Java API better than me.

Comment: I keep getting 0 with this method.  Im testing it with a hashset of 3 words vs a hashset of 3 words...  everytime the result is zero..., sets are un-ordered, one word is common between the two

Comment: Got it!  I was re-using a hashmap.  Thus whenever I re-declared the variable, I had to create a new hashmap instead of just setting it.  THanks for the answer!